# JBoss - Moving the modules directory around

Tags: configuration, jboss, module, location

Wondering if it's possible to move the module directory in a JBoss 7 install to a non-default loco.
Does anyone know of a config param to specify where to pick it up?

Kinda like a conf-dir, bin-dir type of thing.

Thanks,
Aaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's actually possible. As the documentation states, from within the standard launch scripts users are able to manipulate the module path by setting the $JBOSS_MODULEPATH environment variable. (If not set, $JBOSS_MODULEPATH is set to $JBOSS_HOME/modules). The module path is provided to the running process via the -mp command line argument that is set in the standard scripts.

Comment: Cheers mate, really appreciate the help! - Aaron.